# im kinda particular person = i'm picky person ? Is it the same thing?

Tags: word-choice

As you see in the title , are they same meaning ?

İ want to describe a person who choose very elobaretly and fastidiously. I mean the person doen't like everything. He just looks the perfect sitation. "Can i say, He is kind of particular person". OR also can i say "He is picky person."

Comment: You have already used the word that fits perfectly: **fastidious**. You also have *choosy*, *fussy*. And don't forget the article: *He is **a** picky person.*

Answer (score 4):

They are not at all the same. A particular person is careful in their choices for good reasons. "Particular" can (but need not be) a compliment. A picky person makes idiosyncratic choices based on what may seem to be narrow idiosyncratic reasons.

"Fastidious" is probably somewhere in between.

Think of it this way

> I am particular.
> You are fastidious.
> He is a ridiculously picky fool.